# Architecture for Backbone application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, view

I'm new to `backbone.js` so I can't understand the architecture for this application:

```
Page 1:
  User should enter his registration information and click to go to page 2

Page 2:
  User should enter person information and so on, click to go to page 3

Page 3:
  User can read some information based on previously entered information
```

The backend is rails server.

So obviously we will have user model, but what about collection: should we have it in the application?

If we don't have collection, how we will synchronize user's information with server?

How to build views for this kind of application? Thanks

Comment: This is a poor candidatate for a question/answer forum. Recommend you watch the two Railscasts on backbone: http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1

Comment: Thanks, I already saw first and second parts but just because i have no experience with backbone and the difference between current application with traditional architecture is confusing me.

Comment: If you've watched those two videos -- stack overflow isn't going to help. possibly watch: https://peepcode.com/products/backbone-js and http://tekpub.com/products/backbone

Answer (score 0):

We use PhoneGap, jQueryMobile, [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), and [marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) at the client side.
[Here](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals) is a great book from @addyosmani on Backbone. It goes in details on backbone's take on MVC and many of the best practices. In addition to marionette's good documentarian, there is a [chapter](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#marionettejs-backbone.marionette) in the book describes marionette.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Download [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) and see backbone app. This will be the best start who are looking for MVC in javascript.